# How can I get a new string from other strings without simply concatenating them?

Tags: c, algorithm, string

I want to generate a new string from other strings without using concatenation functions or crypto algorithms (md5, rsa, aes, sha256). Specifically, I want to take 2 or 3 (or more) MAC addresses and turn them into 1 unique number (or 1 unique string). For example:

- Be `mac_address_1 = "123abc"`;
- Be `mac_address_1 = "789def"`;
- Put these 2 strings into a function `function(mac_address_1 , mac_address_2)`;
- This function returns a new string `new_string = "1a5c9f"`.

Surely, I could take the first 3 characters from `mac_address_1` and concatenate them with the last 3 characters from `mac_address_2`. But, depending on the application and the hardware manufacturers, this kind of algorithm could generate duplicated `new_string` variables.

Comment: I asked this question to be moved to StackOverflow, but it might seem more like a math question … you have to think about your requirements better. HOW do you want to 'combine' them … if you have a limit of 6 (fixed length?) than it's mathematically not possible to create a guaranteed unique number (assume two values a, b, element of [0, x) and to have a unique combination you need to have 2 * x 'instances' if you do not want duplicates).

Comment: Sounds like you want to a cryptographic hash without calling it a cryptographic hash.

Comment: There'd be no way for you to know that any new address you created was unique. Vendors each control their allocated block of addresses to ensure that duplication doesn't happen.  http://etutorials.org/Networking/Lan+switching+first-step/Chapter+5.+Ethernet+LANs/Media+Access+Control+MAC+Addressing/

Comment: The first three bytes are supposed to specify the vendor, so you should leave them alone.

Comment: it would help if we understand why you want to do this. Where would you use this?

Comment: @bolov. I should take three different MAC addresses and turn them into a unique string to make a registration in a specific cloud server. These 3 MAC addresses are going to be inside a machine. There will be plenty oh those machines. That's why i need something like a UID generated from these 3 MAC addresses.

Comment: @GiordanoCechetMoro would `"MAC1_MAC2"` work?

Comment: @GiordanoCechetMoro: So the result doesn't have to be a valid MAC address itself, it just has to be a unique value derived from two or more MAC addresses.  Do you need to be able to recover the original MACs from that new string?  If all you need is a unique identifier, I'd *strongly* suggest using an existing UUID library, rather than hacking something ad-hoc like this together.

Comment: If new_string has to be the same length as the mac address, it will not really be possible to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @bolov. Unfortunately, not. ```MAC1_MAC2``` is going to be very large for the application itself.

Comment: @JohnBode. That's correct. I don't have to take the original MAC address back. I'll try some existing UUID library as you said.